# Factcheck: Did Australia request 200.000 17 year old girls from Germany in 1946?

Tags: world-war-two, immigration, australia

This text was written in a [newspaper](https://www.nb.no/items/URN:NBN:no-nb_digavis_nordlandsframtid_null_null_19460802_33_59_1?page=1) published in Bodø, Norway on the 2nd of August 1946. It translates to approximately:

> "Girls as war compensation.

> Australia is among the countries that have a shortage of women. As is well known, Germany has a considerable surplus of the same sex, and the government in Sydney has therefore decided to demand a "delivery of 200,000 German girls" as war compensation to bring new life to the Australian male domain. All girls must be under 17 years of age. The Hitleryouth will not be accepted. The government has itself taken on the responsibility for the young girls' upbringing to democratic women."

My students were trying to verify the information in the article and assume it falls in line with [Arthur Calwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Calwell)'s post-war [immigration scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Calwell#:%7E:text=Calwell%20was%20a%20staunch%20advocate,and%20started%20families%20in%20Australia.), but have been unable to find a source for this.

Is there any truth behind what the newspaper published? Have the newspaper altered/muddled the facts?

Comment: The "immigration scheme" referenced is the "White Australia policy", which is a bit more controversial than it would first appear.

Comment: "The Hitleryouth will not be accepted." Good luck finding any, since HJ (or rather BDM) membership was *mandatory*. The only german girls not ex-members of the BDM would be concentration camp survivors. I have no idea if it's true, but it would have been pretty naive/misinformed in any case.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence... There is a ton of literature about the Displaced Persons Program which accepted 170,000 refugees over 5 years, including detailed work by feminist scholars. If there is any real basis to the report quoted it should be easy to find on Google Scholar. I smell parody or something.

Comment: It may be a wrong end of stick thing here. Antipodean countries were keen to encourage immigration from Europe at this time. Given the crap state of Europe at the time, people didn't need to be forced to go either.

Comment: I spent several minutes searching for the relevant article in the scan. It is entitled "Jenter som krigserstattning", in a framed box on the third page of the scan.

Comment: "decided to demand" looks like newspaper-speak for "we heard a rumor this might happen, but it hasn't actually happened". IOW, likely made up, perhaps by someone with an agenda. My guess is you won't be able to find any record of any such thing as a real request, and it would be more informative to your students to dig into the person publishing this propaganda, and why they might have wanted people to believe something like this.

Comment: It seems the Australian government did actively recruit *some* Germans immediately after WW2. Angelika E. Sauer, "Model Workers or Hardened Nazis? The Australian Debate about Admitting German Migrants, 1950-1952." *Australian Journal of Politics and History*, Vol. 45, No. 3, 1999, pp. 422-437: "The basic assumption that German women were harmless was certainly not shared by everybody but was one which both political parties had in common. Immigration Minister Harold Holt later applied the same gendered philosophy in his plan to admit young single women as nurses and domestic servants."

Comment: While "war reparations" is likely hyperbole, it seems that Australia was *aggressively* pursuing white European immigration post WW, including from Norway in meetings in Nov. 1945, see [this paper](http://larsborgersrud.no/boker/meant_to_be_deported.pdf), for example: "... according to both Norwegian and Australian sources, Frydenberg and Debes offered 9,000 children of war to the Australians. The mothers were never mentioned. The delegation was taken on a tour to the former Lebensborn home Godthaab in Bærum, where they could see for themselves how some hundred children of war were living."

Comment: Paywalled: Jan Schmortte, "Attitudes towards German Immigration in South Australia in the post-Second World War Period, 1947-60." *Australian Jounal of Politics and History*, Vol. 51, No. 4, Dec. 2005, pp. 530-544: "Considering the reaction against Germans in Australia during and after the First World War, it is surprising that German immigration to Australia was permitted again soon after the Second World War and even subsidised by the Australian government. [...] This article examines the extent of the Australian public's acceptance of this policy during the period from 1947 to 1960."

Comment: G. Lynch, "‘Australia as the Coming Greatest Foster-Father of Children the World Has Ever Known’: The Post-war Resumption of Child Migration to Australia, 1945-1947", In *UK Child Migration to Australia, 1945-1970: A Study in Policy Failure* (2021), pp. 131-189: "The Commonwealth Government’s ambition was to take advantage of the 
social upheaval across post-conflict Europe to try to attract 50-60,000 child migrants within two or three years of the end of the war. [...] legislation that made the .. Minister of Immigration the legal guardian of all [unaccompanied] child immigrants to Australia

Comment: @njuffa you have more than enough sources there for a proper answer I would say!

Comment: @Brian Z Not really. I know next to nothing about Australia and am missing context. It seems reasonably clear that post WW2 Australia (1) tried hard to attract European immigrants (2) Was interested in child immigration (e.g. orphans) (3) contemplated support infrastructure for child immigrants (4) had no strong objections to German immigrants (5) had some preference for females to achieve gender balance in the immigrant community. The newspaper story may be a distorted reflection of these policies. I tried but failed to find a matching parliamentary discussion or Australian newspaper story.

Comment: @njuffa Right... So how is that not an answer? Do we need a professional historian of Australia to confirm that you've demonstrated, with multiple peer-reviewed sources, precisely what you summarized in your last comment?

Comment: @Vidar Ellingsen Have you tried tackling this from the Norwegian side? In general (don't know for Norway specifically) small local newspapers would condense international news items from the large national newspapers, such as Aftenposten in Norway. Since Norwegian and Australian representatives were discussing a potential transfer of children of war (as I understand, a euphemism for children fathered by the German occupiers with Norwegian women and thus largely unwanted?) in late 1945, some other *hypothetical* schemes *contemplated* by the Australians may have leaked to Norwegian journalists?

Comment: @Brian Z I mostly researched to validate the plausibility of the newspaper article. Modulo some distortions, it now seems plausible to me. However, a few hours of cursory reading did not generate a complete picture in my mind, which until earlier today was pretty much *tabula rasa* with regard to Australian history. I would like my answers to be more than just probabilistic conjecture based on quickly acquired half-knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for a lot of information pertaining to the answer, I have not been able to access any of the big Norwegian newspapers from that time, but I found two more refrences that said about the same (https://www.nb.no/items/c11cbdb6ea425d41bd4b18769e3eb48c?page=1 and https://www.nb.no/items/26fc3ea7402651b03c78738991243fd1?page=1).  In both those articles their girls' age was quoted to be a maximum of 12.  I will supply a translation of the last article in a separate comment.

Comment: This is a translation of an article published in 'Bergen arbeiderblad' 23rd of July 1946 (https://www.nb.no/items/c11cbdb6ea425d41bd4b18769e3eb48c?page=1) titled: "Jenter i krigserstatning": It translates to:

Comment: "Girls as war compensation.
In Australia — in contrast to most other countries — there is a shortage of women. Germany — for reasons not unknown — has a surplus of the female sex. Now the Australian government has decided to demand 200,000 German girls as war reparations to add new life to the Australian male population in the coming years. The girls must indeed be under 12 years old, and former members of the Hitler Youth are not eligible. The government shall ensure that the girls receive a proper — and democratic — upbringing.

Comment: One does not need to be full 12 years old to understand that Germany is not a lasting place, so there is no doubt that the quota will easily be filled."

Comment: @Vidar Ellingsen Please edit this additional information into the question. Am I correct to assume that these are all left-leaning newspapers (social democrats)? I have since found out that post WW2 Australia prioritized children and juveniles *over all other immigrants*. Their plans as early as 1943 was to get kids from orphanages in Britain (not all of them actual orphans) and Scandinavia (see the contemplated *krigsbarn* deal with Norway that ultimately fell through: those kids were younger than 6 and most not even orphans, i.e. parents still alive).

Comment: @Vidar Ellingsen My working hypothesis is that *some* elements of the Australian government with extreme notions about immigration *may* have floated this proposal of getting girls from Germany. I have finally tracked down the hansard (official transcripts) of the Australian parliament, as well as a free archive of the Sydney Morning Herald. Working backwards from August 2, 1946, I have yet to find any information that even remotely resembles the report in *Nordlands Framtid*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - the newspapers in question are not more left-leaning than other Norwegian newspapers (I think).  I've been trying to read the daily telegraph from Sydney from that time, but found no reference as of yet.  Also the publication from "https://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments/frus1946v02/introduction" on the "Council of foregin ministers" in Paris in 45-46 have yielded no answers, but I believe this must have been where these demands have been expressed.

Comment: Well I'm sorry you don't have the answer but you're doing very good history-ing. Just a wild thought - Germany had to pay reparations after the war to Allies - did Australia offer to let Germany off the hook if Germany sent them 200,000 people instead?

Comment: @Vidar Ellingsen The reason I asked whether all newspaper carrying this news item are social-democrat newspapers is because in my experience newspapers with similar political leaning have a tendency to select the same news items, so that it would make sense to check whether the same report (but hopefully with more details) appeared in a Swedish or German newspaper with social-democratic leaning. FWIW, I have not found anything relevant in German publications so far.